# How to write routes when using Laravel in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I'd like to serve my Laravel application in a subfolder in my domain `mydomain.com/project1`. How should I write my routes.php? I'm using something like this:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth','uses' => 'HomeController@index'])->name('home');

// Authentication
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Administração
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administracao', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('filiais', 'FiliaisController');
    Route::resource('precos', 'PrecosController');
    Route::resource('funcionarios', 'FuncionariosController');
    Route::resource('cargos', 'CargosController');
    Route::resource('vendedores', 'VendedoresController');
});

// Comercial
Route::group(['prefix' => 'comercial', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('clientes', 'ClientesController');
    Route::resource('fichas', 'FichasController');
});

// Operacional
Route::group(['prefix' => 'operacional', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('agenda', 'AgendaController');
    Route::resource('os', 'OsController');
    Route::resource('ambientes', 'AmbientesController');
    Route::resource('processos', 'ProcessosController');

    Route::get('relatorios', 'RelatoriosController@index');
    Route::get('relatorios/word/{os}', 'RelatoriosController@word');
    Route::get('relatorios/excel/{os}', 'RelatoriosController@excel');
    Route::get('relatorios/create', 'RelatoriosController@create');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'processo', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('create', 'ProcessoController@create');
        Route::get('index', 'ProcessoController@index');

        Route::post('{os}/parse', 'ProcessoController@parse');

        Route::get('{os}', 'ProcessoController@principal');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{os}/detalhe', 'ProcessoController@detalhe');
        Route::get('{os}/duplicidades', 'ProcessoController@duplicidades');
        Route::get('{os}/restantes', 'ProcessoController@restantes');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{os}/auditoria', 'ProcessoController@auditoria');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{os}/operadores', 'ProcessoController@operadores');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{os}/divergencia', 'ProcessoController@divergencia');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{os}/finalizar', 'ProcessoController@finalizar');
        Route::get('{os}/excluir/{setor}', 'ProcessoController@destroy');
    });
});
```

And I get `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection` for any url. I also tried to add the route prefix `Route::group(['prefix' => 'subfolder'], function () {...}` but it still doesn't recognize

## EDIT

I didn't edit my htaccess and it's:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you installed the application *within* your `project1` folder?

Comment: yep.. I copied the public folder in `project1` folder and the rest of my app I copied outside of public_html, then I edited index.php from public folder to match the framework folder

Comment: try mydomain.com/project1/public

Comment: it doesn't work.. `NotFoundHttpException` again

Comment: my solution works for the homepage only.. the rest doesn't work.. it redirects to `auth/login` but I anything I do i get the same error from there

Comment: I've got nothing left in the tank so I cannot help you further. But I'll leave you with something to consider: Perhaps you might need to look into adjusting your (VirtualHost >) `DocumentRoot` and/or `DirectoryIndex` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html to point to the *new* public directory. Just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: It's a shared hosting.. I don't have access to that :(

Comment: laravel 5 is not meant to be hosted on shared hosting

Comment: i think you need to php composer dumpautoload -o but dunno if u can do that on shared hosting

Comment: I did it before uploading to the server

Answer (score 1):

Go to index.php and change

```
#From this
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
#To this
require __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/bootstrap/autoload.php';


#From this 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
#To this
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/pulcro/bootstrap/app.php'
```

.htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: I updated my question with my .htaccess.. is it correct? I mean.. should I remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`? and what else?